# Record video capture of Webview activity

Tags: android, video, webview, record, capture

I'm trying to find a way to record the screen of the application and more specifically the WebView activity inside the app.

I've done some researches and people suggested using MediaProjectionManager or MediaRecorder APIs for that but I'm not very sure which one and how to implement it.

I looked at some examples and the MediaProjection only record what's in a SurfaceView.. but mine is a Webview, would it still works? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at some examples and the MediaProjection only record what's in a SurfaceView

No. An app using the media projection APIs does not have to have a `SurfaceView` at all. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder) captures a screencast, and it does not have a `SurfaceView`. The media projection APIs capture what is on the *screen*. This could be your app or other apps that are on the screen at the time that you are recording.

> but mine is a Webview, would it still works?

In general, yes, bearing in mind that you are recording what is on the *screen*, so if another application appears (e.g., an incoming phone call), you will be recording that other application. The media projection APIs do not record a `View`, they record the *screen*.

One possible limitation with the media projection APIs would be DRM. It is possible that you will not be able to record everything, because some views are showing DRM-protected content (e.g., playing back a movie), and that might not get captured. I have not played with the media projection APIs in this situation to see how they behave.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs CommonsWare. I use the WebView for showing the live stream from the camera. Would the MediaProjection be able to record it.. without being DRM-protected?

Comment: @emenpy: Um, probably. I have focused my testing on more ordinary applications. I would not be shocked if you encounter some problems, such as jerky output. Going from the device's camera to a `WebView` to a media projection seems... unusual. Why not just use the camera APIs, plus `MediaRecorder`, and just record the camera?

Comment: I just want to record the video that is being played in the Webview inside my app. Can you say a little more on how I could use the Camera API with MediaRecorder to record the camera?

Comment: I think you might have gotten the wrong idea of what I'm intending to do. I have an IP Camera and I'm projecting the video into the app and I would like to record what being played.. I don't want to record  the camera of the device.

Comment: @emenpy: OK. Your first comment said "for showing the live stream from the camera", and in the absence of other context, that would imply the device camera. Still, though, there are going to be more efficient and effective solutions for capturing the stream from the IP camera. Your approach is akin to transferring water from one bucket to another by heating the first bucket, boiling the water, capturing the steam and condensing the steam into water in the other bucket. While this works, it would be far simpler to just pour the water from one bucket to another.

Comment: @emenpy: In your case, read the documentation for your IP camera and determine what protocols and codecs are used for what it publishes. Then, determine how best to capture that stream and save it as a recording. Most likely, somebody will have done this already.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about protocols and codecs of IP Camera,the only thing that I know is that the video output is in Motion JPEG format. I already search for ways to capture stream as recording for IP cam but didn't find many and implementable...

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to do this? Would appreciate if you share some links as well..